# Link appearing as clickable on Heroku, but not on localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

```
<% if @thing.link == ""%>
    <strong><%= @thing.title %></strong>
<% else %>
    <strong><%= link_to @thing.title, "http://#{@thing.link}" %></strong>
 <% end %>
```

Users can enter a link on the creation of a Thing. If they choose not to, the title of the thing will just remain as plain text. If they do decide to include a link, it will link to where they specify.

It works as described locally, but when taken to Heroku, blank links route to about:blank. Why is this? What can I do in order to get Heroku to work correctly with this functionality?

Comment: What does the source look like on Heroku?

Comment: What do you mean? @CDub

Comment: The HTML source for that section of the site.  What is returned as HTML?

Comment: Is `Thing` an database object and do you have same data on your local machine and on heroku?

Comment: The website is http://stynyl.com if you want to check it out. The source indicates that there are link tags around the title that contains no link.

Comment: "http://#{@thing.link}" is redundant.

Comment: @aross - I'm pretty sure my databases are right.

Comment: `link_to @thing.title, @thing should work if thing is an active record instance. else @thing.title, @thing.link should be fine`

Comment: @Senjai - It's not. I included it for a reason. You can see my last question for more information on that.

Comment: @Senjai - `@thing.link` routes to the actual Thing. I want it to link to a link the user types in when creating it. Your suggestion didn't work. That's the way I initially had it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that `link` is nil, not an empty string.  Try:

```
<% if @thing.link.blank? %>
  <strong><%= @thing.title %></strong>
<% else %>
  <strong><%= link_to @thing.title, "http://#{@thing.link}" %></strong>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Let me give that a shot.